# Regular Expression For Searching Variations of a word

Tags: regex, search

OK! I was setting up Inbound Interaction Rule in Desk.com for filtering case and there was an option for using regular expressions. We get lots of mails regarding people complaining of withdrawal related issues. So I'd like to automatically set a label for all withdrawal related issues. But the problem is most people dont mention the word "Withdrawal" exactly as it should be. So can someone help me finding a regular expression for all finding variations of the word withdrawal. Now what I have deduced is that most people either write "Withdrawal/widrawal/widrowal/withdrawalsetc" but basically these words starts with W/w and end with "al" or "als"

Comment: You may want to look at a fuzzy matching library: the idea is precisely to search for slightly different strings with the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

`[Ww].*?[aA][lL]([sS])?`

maybe?

you can also try using `\b` at the start and end as a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Also, I can't help but wonder if this will end up being used evil-ly to ignore all withdrawal related emails where they might be spelling it wrong on purpose to get past your potential 
filters. Just a thought.

UPDATE: `[Ww][A-Za-z]{7}[aA][lL]([sS])?` will match W(anyfiveletters)AL regardless of case. 
you may also consider a range so that you can match between 5 and 7 characters between the `w` and the `al`. EG. `[Ww][A-Za-z]{5,7}[aA][lL]([sS])?` which would match all of your examples since your users cannot seem to spell correctly.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use this but it seems this expression comes true for "withd hshshs rawal" too is there an way to fix the number of characters there must be between w and al in order for the expression to show positive.

Comment: @sherlock Yes. you can use a character set like [A-Za-z] to reflect Any letter (upper or lower case) and then use a [Limiter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) to make your character set match 5 times. I updated my answer to reflect my suggestions